# Fazer o banner aceitar arrastar a imagem

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Olá, estou usando um [banner slider jquery](https://devrama.com/static/devrama-slider/). Gostaria de saber como fazer ele aceitar arrastar a imagem para passar o slide. Em suas opções não há, mas alguém sabe como implementar esse recurso, sem precisar trocar de plugin? pois preciso que seja ele, não posso trocar

Comment: Implementar isso em Javascript parece bem complexo, ainda mais utilizando outro plugin junto

Comment: imagino algo com a função sortable.. para ter aquele drag and drop na imagem sabe..

Comment: alguns sliders já possuem.. mas gostaria de implementar nesse, devrama, pq tem outros recursos nele para efeito no texto e imagem, que são bem flexiveis